# How can I upload data 3D model through storage API in furniture library

Tags: html, augmented-reality, aframe, archilogic, 3d.io

How can I upload data 3D model through storage API in furniture library?

I am using furniture library from https://furniture.3d.io/ and I want to upload product in this library.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately uploading your own 3D models into the 3d.io furniture library is not possible at this time.

What you can do is to upload your 3D model to [archilogic](https://docs.archilogic.com/en/tutorials/custom-3d-content/index.html), and then use the 3d.io [scene API](https://3d.io/docs/api/1/scene.html) to easily access it and if you want convert it to A-Frame components which you can then use to create your own library.

Here's a video on how to do that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwj0HvF2JzU

And here's the documentation about how to convert your scene to A-Frame components: https://3d.io/docs/api/1/scene.html#get-a-frame-elements